# How to remove initial null value?

Tags: java, servlets

I am uploading a file and displaying it as a link...but initially when I load the the page it displays a null value...I want remove this null value...

```html
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="./FileUploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" ><%  String name= request.getParameter("name");%>File:
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
    <a href="./file/<%=name%>"><%=name%></a>
```

FileUploadServlet.java

```
// Create path components to save the file
final String docs="C:\\Users\\tushar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\fileupload\\web\\file\\";

final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
final String file = getFileName(filePart);String a=request.getParameter("id");
     OutputStream out = null;
InputStream filecontent = null;
final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter(); try{
out = new FileOutputStream(new File(docs +""+file));  
    filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }


    response.sendRedirect("upload.jsp?id="+a+"&name="+file+"");


 //   LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}", new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
    if (filecontent != null) {
        filecontent.close();
    }
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: Just check if the parameter is different from null before printing the link.

Comment: its proper bcoz when i upload a  file it comes as a link...

Answer (score 0):

Initially when you load the page there's no file uploaded, resulting in the name being null.

You can set the name as `""` initially or have a null check in the JSP, either of which will remove the initial null.

Your value is being sent in `response.sendRedirect("upload.jsp?id="+a+"&name="+file+"");` this so set the file variable here to a value or an empty string to avoid the null value.